# How to add additional lambda expression to IQueryable CreateQuery

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

Here is my original select query which works for one field "SurveyName":

```
    public static IQueryable Select(this IQueryable source, string selector, params object[] values)
    {
        LambdaExpression lambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(source.ElementType, null, "SurveyName", values); //SurveyName is hard coded here as example
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(
            Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable), "Select",
                new Type[] { source.ElementType, lambda.Body.Type },
                source.Expression, Expression.Quote(lambda)));
    }
```

I want to add second lambda expression and I tried below:

```
    public static IQueryable Select(this IQueryable source, string selector, params object[] values)
    {
        LambdaExpression lambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(source.ElementType, null, "SurveyName", values); //SurveyName is hard coded as example
        LambdaExpression lambda2 = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(source.ElementType, null, "SurveyHeaderName", values); //SurveyHeaderName is hard coded as example

        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(
            Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable), "Select",
                new Type[] { source.ElementType, lambda.Body.Type, lambda2.Body.Type },
                source.Expression, Expression.Quote(lambda)));
    }
```

Which give me

> No generic method 'Select' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is
>   compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type
>   arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic

How to achieve add additional lambda expression (I mean additional field `Select SurveyName, SurveyHeaderName`)

Hear is "lambda" screen shot in debug

[image]

As giving more details, why I use above code, here is frontend part:

```
public class SurveyQuestionSurveyHeaderSurvey
{
    public SurveyQuestion SurveyQuestion { get; set; }
    public SurveyHeader SurveyHeader { get; set; }
    public Survey Survey { get; set; }

    public String SurveyName { get; set; }
    public String SurveyHeaderName { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<SurveyQuestionReportViewModel> SurveyQuestionReportExcel(IDataTablesRequest dataTablesRequest, out int totalCount)
{
    var res0 = from sq in _uow.Repository<SurveyQuestion>().Queryable()
               join s in _uow.Repository<Survey>().Queryable()
               on sq.SurveyHeader.SurveyId equals s.SurveyId
               select new SurveyQuestionSurveyHeaderSurvey { SurveyQuestion = sq, Survey = s, SurveyHeader = sq.SurveyHeader, SurveyName = s.Name };


    List<Expression<Func<object, bool>>> _expression;
    List<Expression<Func<object, object>>> _includes;

    _includes = new List<Expression<Func<object, object>>>();
    _expression = new List<Expression<Func<object, bool>>>();
    Func<IQueryable<object>, IOrderedQueryable<object>> _orderBy;

    if (dataTablesRequest.GetSearchListParameter() != null)
        _expression.Add(DynamicQueryable.WhereLambdaExpression<object>(dataTablesRequest.GetSearchListParameter()));

    if (dataTablesRequest.GetOrderByParameter() != null)
        _orderBy = p => p.OrderBy(dataTablesRequest.GetOrderByParameter());
    else
        _orderBy = p => p.OrderBy("ID Desc");

    var fields = String.Join(",", dataTablesRequest.Columns.Select(x => x.Data).ToArray()).TrimEnd(',');
    fields = "SurveyName";
    var toto = res0.Select(fields, null, _expression, _orderBy, _includes, dataTablesRequest.Start, dataTablesRequest.Length);


    var result = res0.Include(p => p.SurveyHeader.Survey).Where(x => x.SurveyHeader.SurveyId == 3074)
       .Select(x => new SurveyQuestionReportViewModel
       {
           SurveyQuestionId = x.SurveyQuestion.SurveyQuestionId,
           SurveyName = x.SurveyHeader.Survey.Name,
           Name = "Genel Sonuç",
           HeaderName = x.SurveyHeader.Name,
           QuestionName = x.SurveyQuestion.Description,
       });
    totalCount = 10;
    return result;

}
```

Comment: Taking a shot in the dark here but your new Type[] seems to be passing two values.  If you're creating a new Type, for each type you create wouldn't it need a matching value.  It could inherit the same the same type for each value.  Also, your Expression.Quote is also only accounting for the first lambda expression, not the second.  Why not just use LINQ here?

Comment: Where does `DynamicExpression.ParseLambda` come from?

Comment: In C# you can't do `select fieldA, fieldB` but must create an anonymous object with `select new { fieldA, fieldB }`. Are you used to VB perhaps?

Comment: @DavidG it is part of library created by previous developer

Comment: So how do you expect anyone to help with code you're not showing us?

Comment: Also note your attempt doesn't pass `lambda2` at all, so it can't be used in the `Call` anyway. Can you provide a translation for `lambda` and `lambda2` as C# code?

Comment: @DavidG it gives simply as result : `lambda = {Param_0 => Param_0.SurveyName}`

Comment: The problem is that you need a different lambda, not a second one. What you are doing is trying to effectively call `Select(lambda, lambda2)`

Comment: @NetMage I added screenshot, can you see it? I can't due to imgur blocked in my area

Comment: I see it, it is not terribly helpful,  but the important part (`lambda` = `Param_0 => Param_0.SurveyName`) is there. But it isn't valid in C# to do `Select(p => p.SurveyName, p => p.SurveyHeaderName)`, you normally would do `Select(p => new { p.SurveyName, p.SurveyHeaderName })`. Unfortunately dynamically creating an anonymous object is painful in lots of ways and not terribly useful. Consider what you would like if you wrote a static `Select()` call?

Comment: My library support for single field or single entity for selecting, I want to achieve select for multiple field. I am using this structure for `public IEnumerable<SurveyQuestionReportViewModel> SurveyQuestionReport(IDataTablesRequest dataTablesRequest, out int totalCount)`

Comment: So what type do you expect to get back from a multiple field `Select()` call for one row?

Comment: @NetMage Please see edit why I am trying to use library code, it is datatable with fields, filters and sorting.

Comment: Helpful, but I don't think it answers my question...

Answer (score 0):

I first build my lambda expression by:

```
    static Expression<Func<T, T>> BuildLambda<T>()
    {
        var createdType = typeof(T);
        var displayValueParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "Param_0");
        var ctor = Expression.New(createdType);
        var bindings = new List<MemberAssignment>();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            Expression left = Expression.Property(displayValueParam, propertyInfo);
            var displayValueProperty = propertyInfo;
            bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(displayValueProperty, left));

        }
        var memberInit = Expression.MemberInit(ctor, bindings);
        return
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(memberInit, displayValueParam);
    }
```

And my select is :

```
    public static IQueryable<T> Select<T>(this IQueryable source,  IDataTablesRequest dataTablesRequest, out int totalCount)
    {

        var lambda = BuildLambda<T>();
        var query = source.Provider.CreateQuery(
            Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable), "Select",
                new Type[] { source.ElementType, lambda.Body.Type },
                source.Expression
                , Expression.Quote((Expression)lambda)
                ));
        if (dataTablesRequest.GetSearchListParameter() != null)
            query = query.Where(dataTablesRequest.GetSearchListParameter());
        totalCount = query.Count();


        if (dataTablesRequest.GetOrderByParameter() != null)
            query = query.OrderBy(dataTablesRequest.GetOrderByParameter(), null);

        query = query.Skip(dataTablesRequest.Start).Take(dataTablesRequest.Length);

        return (IQueryable<T>)query;
    }
```